# regex match failing

Tags: python

I have the following regex which should only match line2,I only want to match lines with `Revert`why is the regex matching line 1 aswell?how to fix it such that it only matches line2 and does not match line1?

```
revert_change = False
line1 = '<change://problem/16539021> Align RNG buffers to 14 bytes to make sure it is aligned'
line2 = 'Revert <change://problem/16539021> Align RNG buffers to 14 bytes to make sure it is aligned'

if re.findall("(?!.*(Revert|revert))[\S]*(?:change:\/\/problem\/)(\d{8,8})", line1):
    match = re.findall("(?!.*(Revert|revert))[\S]*(?:rdar:\/\/problem\/)(\d{8,8})", line1)
    print "Revert change detected...%s"%match
    revert_change = True
print revert_change
```

OUTPUT:-

```
True
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
FALSE
```

Comment: Your current pattern actually already does match line 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a wrong logic.

```
(?!.*(Revert|revert))
  ^
```

This, combined with `re.match`, asserts that there's **no** `Revert` or `revert` in the string.

To negate the assertion, change `(?!` to `(?=`

```
(?=.*(Revert|revert))......
  ^
```

Note that `(?=` and `(?!` are lookaheads, they ensure that the regex matches the upcoming part, without actually matching it. If you want to match `Revert`, just use a regular group:

```
.*?(?:Revert|revert)\s*\S*(?:change:\/\/problem\/)(\d{8})
^^^^^^              ^^^^^^
```

Comment: this works for the case of not matching line 1 but this does not match line2 either which has the word"Revert"